# Error de VirtualBox Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Tags: virtualbox

tengo mi ordenador con Ubuntu 20.04 y he instalado virtualbox porque necesito una máquina virtual con Windows 7, una vez configurada la máquina, al iniciarla me aparece el siguiente error:

> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up
> correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing
> '/sbin/vboxconfig' as root. If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled
> you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt,
> vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux
> system's documentation for more information. where: suplibOsInit what:
> 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not
> installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

Con detalles:

> Fallo al abrir una sesión para la máquina virtual W7. The virtual
> machine 'W7' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code
> 1 (0x1). Código resultado: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Componente:
> MachineWrap Interfaz: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}

He intentado agregar los elementos básicos de compilación con: `sudo apt install build-essential`
Y construir los módulos del kernel con:

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

Al hacer el sudo me aparece lo siguiente:

> vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
> vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
> vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
> vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
> There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
> /sbin/vboxconfig
> as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
> kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
> them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.*vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
> vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
> vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
> vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
> There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
> /sbin/vboxconfig
> as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
> kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
> them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

Comment: Qué sale en `journalctl -xe` al hacer `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` ? Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade esta información

Comment: He intentado mirar el dmesg pero no veo nada relacionado con virtualbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En `dmesg` seguro no ves nada a nivel de aplicación; lo que aparecerá serán cosas de EFI o de levantar la nueva interfaz de red, etc.

Es necesario que confirmes si estás usando *Secure boot* en tu BIOS y si usas UEFI en tu Ubuntu. Si es así, te espera <strike>llanto y rechinar de dientes</strike> un camino largo. Si revisas [este post en AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900118/vboxdrv-sh-failed-modprobe-vboxdrv-failed-please-use-dmesg-to-find-out-why), verás que es necesario seguir UNO de estos dos caminos:

**a)** Configurar la BIOS y revisar que no use SecureBoot (y ver si tu Ubuntu no se queja en el proceso o toca rehacer el UEFI como MBR [(respuesta no aceptada pero bien votada)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1026251/127667) , o devolver ese cambio y

**b)** firmar todos los módulos de VirtualBox [(respuesta aceptada)](https://askubuntu.com/a/900121/127667) y volver a hacer modprobe.

Comment: Respondiendo preguntas off-topic ... no me parece correcto. te recomiendo https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Pues no existe SuperUser en español para mover la pregunta o enviarles allí. SI quieres ser así de estricto, es tu rep y son tus votos para que los uses como consideres.

Comment: pues lamento comentarte que no es que sea estricto ... son las normas del sitio ...

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente hice lo que decía la caja de diálogo. Ejecuté en consola el comando y lo resolvió solo:

> sudo /sbin/vboxconfig